# How well does elasticsearch compress data?

Tags: compression, elasticsearch

I am looking to scope the servers required for an elasticsearch proof-of-concept.

Ultimately, my question is this:

**Given 1GB of json text indexed by elasticsearch, how much can I expect to be occupied on disk by elasticsearch?**

Obviously there are many variables, but I'm going for orders of magnitude. 100MB? 100GB?

I understand that elasticsearch performs compression ( http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/store/ ), but I don't know what kind of footprint the indexes and other structures occupy.

Anecdotal answers are acceptable, but please also let me know what version you're using.

Comment: 150 MB, that's approx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is:  it depends.

A blog post by [Adrien Grand, who works on Elasticsearch](http://blog.jpountz.net/post/33247161884/efficient-compressed-stored-fields-with-lucene) did some benchmarking with this from the Lucene standpoint.  It looks like he was getting about 2x improvement.

He also mentions [LUCENE-4226](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-4226), where some of this underlying compression work was done.  There's a few benchmarks listed within, comparing the various compression algorithms tested.

As well, based on this [Elasticsearch 0.19.5 release announcement](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/0-19-5-released/), it appears that store-level compression defaults to LZF, with Snappy coming some time in the future.  Further looking around showed that Snappy experimental support appeared in 0.19.9

Comment: I neglected to search for Lucene in my research, which I should have. Links have been informative.